# Switch the integer to its opposite in python

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is some built in function in python that will change whatever the sign of an integer is to its opposite.

example of what I'm looking for:

```
num = 1
num2 = -2

# where flip() is a hypothetical function

flip(num)
flip(num2)

print(num)
print(num2)

>>> -1
>>> 2
```

I know how to create my own function to do this, but it seems there may be a built-in, or some short hand way to go about it.

Comment: Why Do you need some in-built method if you can simply do `-1 * whatever` ?

Comment: Integers are immutable in Python.  There is no possibility of a ``flip(num)`` call that would change the value of ``num``: it would have to be ``num = flip(num)``.  Of course, ``num = -num`` would be a simpler way to accomplish that.

Comment: I actually just realized that this works. I overlooked it thinking it wouldn't effect a number that was already negative. Simple math, two negatives equal a positive. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

So this was actually way more simple than I was trying to make it.

```
num1 = 1

num1 = -num1

print(num1)

>>> -1

num1 = -num1

print(num1)

>>> 1
```

Two negatives equal a positive